# How to stop execution of a Python script without closing Blender too?

Tags: python

I'm debugging my Python code and I wanted to make my script only execute until a certain line, so I can easily see what is happening.

```
# python code I want to execute

break_here_and_let_me_read_the_console_output()

# more python code I don't want to execute
```

I've found out that there's Python's built-in functions like `exit()` and `quit()`. The problem is - if I use them, not only my script it terminated, but the whole Blender instance that I was running that script inside is terminated too.

How can I stop only my script, but not Blender itself?

Comment: The only way I know to 'terminate' a script is using the return {'FINISHED'}. This is used in operator scripts though...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not too elegant, but it will stop the script in the middle and won't close Blender:

```
raise KeyboardInterrupt()
```

Comment: `BaseException` is a type you should never raise. I think raising an exception is a good idea, but I would rather choose `KeyboardInterrupt` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Could I check if a key is pressed in a loop, and exit the loop if pressed? Ideally, the key press would be cached, so timing wouldn't need to be perfect?